# How to change the image dynamically inside the bootstrap body onclicking with the different images in laravel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

[image: This my currently existing view.Here On clicking with the thumbnail image it should display on the bootstrap body]Laravel view code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="images" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Images</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-content">
    <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class = "col-sm-6" align="center">
    <div >
    <a href = "#" class="upload" >
     <img src="" width="250" 
     height="250" class="someClass">
      <button type="button" align="center"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-upload"></span>Upload photo</button>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Image Guidelines</h3><br/>
    Remember!!
    <ul>
    <li>Upload authentic product photos taken in bright lighting.</li>
    <li>Use clear color images with minimum resolution of 1100x1100px.
    </li>
    <li> Maximum Images supported :- 5</li>
     <li> Minimum Images required :- 1</li>
     <li>Minimum Image Resolution :- 1100x1100</li>
    <li>Image should be having pure white or light grey background.
     </li>
     <li>Image shouldn’t be blurred.</li>
      <li>Product should occupy 80% of space in image.</li>
    <li>Include all products in primary image (first image).</li>
   </ul>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div>

  **<a  href="#">
  <img src="haghwaylitecontroller.jpg" alt="gemcamera" 
  style="width:150px" class="upload1">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
  <img src="lightningswitchmodule.jpg" alt="gemcamera" 
  style="width:150px" class="upload1">
  </a>
  <a href="#" >
  <img src="videodoorphone.jpg" alt="gemcamera" style="width:150px" 
  class="upload1">
  </a>**
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
    dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login" 
    onclick="javascript:validate()">SAVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my bootstrap code inside laravel view. It includes thumbails of images which is marked in block.On clicking with the images,the same image should display in the bootsrap body(ie., the clicked image should display on the image source tag which is inside the bootstrap body has the class name of **someClass**)

**Script code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click", ".upload1", function() {
 var imageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
// alert(imageSRC);

  $('#images').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".someClass").attr("src", imageSRC);
    });

 </script>
```

This is the script code I have tried for my requirement.

Comment: Hello!! is there anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep only this line once you store the value in imageSRC variable

```
$(".someClass").attr("src", imageSRC);
```